# Does my bearded dragon have anything wrong with him?

Tags: health, reptiles, lizards, bearded-dragon

He is acting relatively normal but he is in brumation so he is less active. I have little to no experience with these kind of things, since he is my first reptile, and I got him 6 months ago.

The scales on the tip of his nose are black and the area around it is orange in color or darker grey. The scales don't look like the rest of his body and I just want to make sure he's okay.

Comment: "Burns toon"? Translation,  please?

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: The answer [might be in this Q&A](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/what-is-this-dull-patch-on-my-bearded-dragon). If not, a picture is probably necessary.

Comment: If the other question does not provide the answer you are looking for, please post a picture and we can re-open this question.