# Shedding bearded Dragon, has a white grey spot

Tags: reptiles, lizards, bearded-dragon

My bearded Dragon is shedding her whole back but she has a white grey spot is there anyone that's experience that with their bearded Dragon?

Feeling really concerned

Comment: Do you have a photo?  You probably don't have enough rep to post the photo here, but if you put a link to it, someone with more rep will add the photo to your question.

Comment: check this page [here](https://www.beardeddragon.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=93592), this could be the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It shouldnt be anything serious, there is a nice answer to a similar question [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2109/6901) that describes (what sounds to me) like exactly the same problem. There is also a good picture to go along with it. Also if you want to read the same thing from a forum i found check my comment on the question. It seems to me like it is a shedding problem and a lukewarm bath should help the beardie along with that.

**make sure it is lukewarm and not warmer**.

We are at 98 degrees so if we think it is warm reptiles will think it is scalding.