# Black spot/patch on my bearded dragons back

Tags: health, reptiles

My bearded dragon has a black spot/patch on her back.  She has had it for. Month or two.  Ive been giving her a bath in betadine just in case of infection but it doesn't seem to be going away. Can someone please tell me what it is so i can help my beardie. Id post a picture if i can figure it out.  Thank you

Comment: at the top there are a few buttons and one of them is an image button. It looks like a square with mountains in it. You can edit your post and place the image or send it to a mod and they can put it for you. The dull patch may be the infection as seen in the answer [here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2109/6901)

Comment: If you can post a link to the picture uploaded to another site (like imgur or flickr) one of our higher rep users will be able to edit it into your question for you.